# Why Material-UI is not recognizing the theme.spacing function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

## Description

I am trying to use Material-UI's **theme.spacing** function in a React application but the **spacing** function is not recognized.

The Javascript error message is: **TypeError: theme.spacing is not a function**

I am unsure if this is a bug or I have something wrong with the frameworks versions being installed.

---

## Context

- Here's [the Github issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/14474) raised to address this problem.
- Here's [the repo](https://github.com/lesair/create-react-app) with the offending code. The error is caught in the [src\pages\index.js](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/create-react-app/src/pages/index.js) file, line 16:
  `paddingTop: theme.spacing(20)`
- Here's [the sandboxed repo running](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/lesair/create-react-app) where you can actually see the error message.

These are the frameworks versions being installed, according to the **package-lock.json** file:

- Material-UI: v3.9.2
- React: v16.8.1
- Chrome: v72.0.3626.96
- TypeScript: None
- create-react-app: v3.2.2

Comment: This can be cause also from migration from v. 4 to v5 of Material UI and can be solved in different way depeding where the default Theme is been called https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67434882/reactjs-typeerror-theme-spacing-is-not-a-function/70303100#70303100

Comment: Also have to be careful of the emotion library interacting with the theme of things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it turns out this is a bug after all, caused by [request #14099](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/14099).

A fix is on the way now, so I am closing this question.

Comment: Im using MUI5 and still getting this issue

Comment: I'm using MUI v5.13 and I still am getting this issue.

Answer (score 6):

For material ui version 5.1.0
the following worked for me (as @Worm said)

- importing makestyles like this

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
```

remember to install `@mui/styles`

if you get a warning like

```sh
MUI: The `styles` argument provided is invalid.
You are providing a function without a theme in the context.
One of the parent elements needs to use a ThemeProvider.
MUI: The `styles` argument provided is invalid.
You are providing a function without a theme in the context.
One of the parent elements needs to use a ThemeProvider.
```

wrap parent container with ThemeProvider

```js
export default ParentComponentName = (props)=>{
return(
   <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <SomeThemeComponent>
        <SomeComponent />
      </SomeThemeComponent>
    <ThemeProvider>
)
}
```

### Reference

https://mui.com/styles/api/#examples-4

PS: posted as new answer as I couldn't comment,because of credit limits.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles' 
const userStyles = makeStyles (theme => ({
gridAlign : {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.secondary,
  },
})
```

Comment: I am using this approach only, but still I get the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Before: `import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';` would work.

But now in the latest material UI versions we need to add the following import:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
```

Comment: This seems to target material ui v4

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading the @material-ui/core package to minimum version of 4.0.0. 
Run **npm i @material-ui/core@4.0.0** 
It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

just do it next way:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  status: {
    danger: orange[500],
  },
});

export default function CustomStyles() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CustomCheckbox />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the import makes the bug go away:

```js
import {makeStyles} from "@material-ui/**core**/styles";
```

Answer (score 1):

Using MUI version 5 (V5.0.3), I get this error because the import of makeStyles must be

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
```

See here for the documentation: https://mui.com/styles/api/#heading-makestyles-styles-options-hook

Answer (score 1):

with MUI V5 use `npm install tss-react`. https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#migrate-from-jss

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The theme.spacing function is provided by the @mui/system package and not the @mui/material package.
So instead of calling it as :

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    '& .MuiTextField-root': {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: '25ch',
    },
  },
}));
```

Call it as :

```
import { spacing } from '@mui/system';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    '& .MuiTextField-root': {
      margin: spacing(1),
      width: '25ch',
    },
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code as following, and it works for me now.

Original

```
paddingTop: theme.spacing(20)
```

Modified

```
paddingTop: theme => theme.spacing(20)
```

I am using Material UI 5.13 version.